# Yarn can't add dependency via git+ssh because package doesn't have a "_uid"

Tags: yarnpkg

We have a dependency that lives on private GitLab instance, but we can't get yarn to add it.

Installing the package like this:

`yarn add git+ssh://git@privateserver.org:team/package-name.git`

results in this error:

`error Package "package-name@0.9.2" doesn't have a "_uid".`

I'm thinking this is yarn-specific because using npm does work ... e.g. this command successfully installs the package:

`npm install --save git+ssh://git@privateserver.org:team/package-name.git`

I've looked through yarn's documentation and gone through pages of google results, but can't really find any information the `_uid`. Anyone have any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Think we have it figured out. It appears that in our case, we have to supply a hash ... either a partial SHA or tag.

So this works:

`yarn add git+ssh://git@privateserver.org:team/package-name.git#8050948`

and so does this:

`yarn add git+ssh://git@privateserver.org:team/package-name.git#master`